# Texture disappears when rendering in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, transparency

I am trying to render a scene in Blender using the cycles engine, and i have here a texture with transparency. First it was rendering black because of it but then i fixed the problem with a Transparent BSDF and mix nodes in the shader. It looks fine in the preview, but when i try to render the image the texture almost disappears completely. The first picture is made in preview, the second one in render.

[image: preview image]

[image: render image]

Comment: Hello, are you talking about the leaves of the plant? Could you please share the plant object? Don't forget to pack the image if you've used one: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonbots here is the file of the whole scene as it is a single object[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=eYdvJXQz" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/eYdvJXQz/)
Yes, i am talking about the plant, the other textures don't have transparency so they are fine

Comment: Please pack the images before sharing (File > External Data > Pack Resources)  ;)

Comment: Oh i'm sorry i didn't know it is required. Here it is [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Xb0qeK3q" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Xb0qeK3q/)

Comment: it works fine for me, in both Eevee and Cycles, weird...

Comment: well it must be some computer problem then, thanks for investing your time anyway